# How to load a scene in a storyboard from a view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, view, controller, storyboard

I am developing an application that loads a web page (using UIWebView) using Storyboard (I do know nothing about previous xib neither). I have already created a view controller for that UIWebView and everything works fine. The thing is: since previous versions of iOS don't allow to upload files, I need to make a new view (scene I thought it is called) that allows the user to pick and post a picture. I am able to develop both views separately and they work as expected but now I need to connect them based on event triggered when user wants to post a picture to the server. Using shouldStartLoadWithRequest I can catch that action, then I need to redirect to new view (which contains image picker and a button in order to upload the selected image) if iOS version is below 6.0 but I am really lost when it comes to load the new controller to show that view. Using buttons it is trivial but I don't know how to called inside the code. So far, I have a view controller linked to that scene and I have tried these ways:

```
WritePostViewController *postViewController = [[WritePostViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:postViewController animated:YES];
```

And even calling the storybard:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
[sb instantiateInitialViewController];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WritePostView"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The first approach does nothing and second one shows this error log:

*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:  Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'WritePostView'*

I have been browsing and reading a lot but nothing solves my problem. For sure this a problem with my not-so-large knowledge about iOS but I am really stuck. I will thank any help.

By the way, I need to come back after posting the file but I could imagine it is the same way opposite direction, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code is inside a view controller (which it seems to be), you can get the current storyboard with `self.storyboard`.  You also don't need `instantiateInitialViewController` because, if all your UI is coming from the same storyboard, it has already gone through the loading of the initial controller.

As for the actual error, it's complaining that @"WritePostView" isn't a recognized name for any view controller in the storyboard.  Note that what it looks for here is **not** the class name for the controller but the Storyboard ID for the controller.  (Which makes sense since you could have different "scenes" with the same **type** of controllers.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems is solved. I just have added a *segue* between scenes

[image: segue identifier]

and then I just need to add this one:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"writePostViewSegue" sender:self];
```

and it works!. Anyway, I am not sure if it is the way to do it, so if someone knows better, please let me know.

Cheers

Comment: The answer I posted above assumed that you wanted to use `presentViewController:` in code for some reason.  :)  If a segue works for you, it's a better solution.

Comment: A brief look at the image attached shows a segue loop. Each segue is creating a new copy and stacking every higher instead of re-using the existing controllers. This will cause many problems from "lost" data to rampant memory usage.

Comment: Yes, I have realized that I must use a modal view and close it after action is done (save a post). I have changed this avoiding segue loop.